# How to create dictionary with list of string as value from grouped data using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I came into a Linq issue. I read data from a csv file and split it by **";"**. By this step, the value is in the format like:

```
{string[3]}: "Type1","good","this"
{string[3]}: "Type2","bad","that"
{string[3]}: "Type1","normal","those"
```

Now I want to use linq to convert it to a **Dictionary<string,List>**. The value in the list should be the **third** value in the each string array. I use **GroupBy()** to group them and **ToDictionary()** to convert to dictionary. But I failed to do that. The code I use is

```
    var dimData = System.IO.File.ReadLines(PathofOutputFile).Select(line => line.Split(';')).
                  GroupBy(data => data[0], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).
                  ToDictionary(data => data.Key, data => data.First()[2], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I know the problem lies in the parameters in the **ToDictionary()** function. My code only gets the first match. But I cannot figure out how to create a list of string inside the function.

Could someone gives me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: You're asking for only the first match when you use ` data.First()`. What *do* you want the output to be though? You have two `Type1` records. What should the dictionary hold for that type? `this`? `those`? `this,those`?

Comment: why do you want a list, when you store only a single item into it? Anyway it'll be helpful if you would provide some sample-data of your actual file, as it's pretty ahrd to figure out what you're splitting and grouping here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh I forgot to mention that. For Type1 I want this, those in a list of string.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Because there are cases like Type1, which appears multiple times. In that case, I want all the third value in a list of string, whose key is "Type1".

Comment: Please consider using a CSV parser. You'll avoid getting in lot of troubles (CSV has many possible variations)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
    // Read the lines from the file, split them by ';', and group them by the first value
    // then create a dictionary with the key and list of third column values 
    var dictionary = File.ReadLines(inputCsvFile)
        .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
        .GroupBy(data => data[0], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        .ToDictionary(
        group => group.Key,
        group => group.Select(data => data[2]).ToList(),
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    // Show content of the dictionary 
    foreach (var entry in dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", entry.Value));
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: good, but why bother with 'groups`?

Comment: @NetMage Ok, I skipped groups....:)